# Nested Dictionary merge with default value dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I have 2 nested dictionaries that have some matching keys and similar structure, and want to merge them into a final third dictionary in a specific way. A default value dictionary, has the values that will be used if not in the second dictionary, which will have some keys that match, and some keys that dont exist.  In either event I want it to overwrite the default key or add a new key from the second dictionary to this third dictionary. See (shortened) example below:

default:

```
 {"model_name": "null",
 "description": "null",
 "frequency": "d",
 "tasks": [
 {
   "target": "elastic",
   "metrics": "null",
   "model_type": "null",
   "alert": {
     "type": "pagerduty",
     "threshold": 5,
     "service_id" : "P94CEA6"
     }
    }
   ]
  }
```

second dict

```
{"model_name": "dqs_cie_registration_09",
"description": "test cie registration",
"tasks": [
{
  "source": "elastic",
  "metrics": [
    "indid_unique_cnt", "zs"
  ],
  "model_type": "Deep_Dive",
  "elastic_config": "config",
  "read_object": "dqs_rtfs_d_*",
  "watcher": "cie_watch_zs_3d.json",
  "target_write_index": "dqs_target_write_index"
   }
  ]
 }
```

Id like to merge it so it results in

```
{"model_name": "dqs_cie_registration_09",
"description": "test cie registration",
"frequency": "d",
"tasks": [
{
  "target": "elastic",
  "source": "elastic",
  "metrics": ["indid_unique_cnt", "zs"],
  "model_type": "Deep_Dive",
  "elastic_config": "config",
  "read_object": "dqs_rtfs_d_*",
  "watcher": "cie_watch_zs_3d.json",
  "target_write_index": "dqs_target_write_index",
  "alert": {
     "type": "pagerduty",
     "threshold": 5,
     "service_id" : "P94CEA6"
   }
  ]
}
```

The third dict merges the second dict on the first.

I haven't really gotten anywhere but I feel there is a really easy way to implement this that I just don't remember.

Comment: You'll need to use dictionary update() - make a copy of the default dictionary and update it with the second dictionary.

Comment: you are trying to update things inside the list entries as well right?

Comment: The supplied data is incorrect. please provide correct values before asking the question

Comment: @Buckeye14Guy yes- the "tasks" lists will always be just one element in this case

Comment: The supplied 2nd dictionary seems slightly incorrect for "tasks".

Comment: @DarrylG how so?

Comment: @akrauss--simplest to check is to assign it as a variable in python and run the script.  You will get an error.  From there you will see there is a slight issue.

Comment: @DarrylG I saw- sorry was removing some fields from actually dicts to make the sample more concise, left out a }

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? What's stopping you?

Answer (score 0):

Following merge routine produces desired result

```
import copy    # to provide deepcopy
import pprint  # Pretty Print

def merge(a, b):
  " Merges b into a (to preserve a make a deepcopy prior to calling merge "
  if isinstance(a, dict) and isinstance(b, dict):
    " Dictionaries "
    for k, v in b.items():
      if k in a:
        # Conditionally add keys from b
        if isinstance(a[k], str):
          if a[k] == "null":
              a[k] = copy.deepcopy(b[k])
        else:
          merge(a[k], b[k])
      else:
        # Add keys from b
        a[k] = copy.deepcopy(b[k])

  elif isinstance(a, list) and isinstance(b, list):
    " Lists "
    if len(a) == len(b):
      for i, item in enumerate(b):
        if isinstance(item, str) and isinstance(b[i], str):
          if item == "null":
            a[i] = b[i]
        else:
          merge(a[i], b[i])
```

**Usage**

```
d1 = {"model_name": "null",
 "description": "null",
 "frequency": "d",
 "tasks": [
 {
   "target": "elastic",
   "metrics": "null",
   "model_type": "null",
   "alert": {
     "type": "pagerduty",
     "threshold": 5,
     "service_id" : "P94CEA6"
     }
    }
   ]
  }

d2 = {"model_name": "dqs_cie_registration_09",
"description": "test cie registration",
"tasks": [
{
  "source": "elastic",
  "metrics": [
    "indid_unique_cnt", "zs"
  ],
  "model_type": "Deep_Dive",
  "elastic_config": "config",
  "read_object": "dqs_rtfs_d_*",
  "watcher": "cie_watch_zs_3d.json",
  "target_write_index": "dqs_target_write_index"
   }
  ]
 }

merge(d1, d2) # to preserve d1 create a deepcopy prior to merge (i.e. temp = copy.deepcopy(d1))
pp = pprint.PrettyPrinter(indent=4)

pp.pprint(d1)
```

**Output**

```
{   'description': 'test cie registration',    
    'frequency': 'd',    
    'model_name': 'dqs_cie_registration_09',    
    'tasks': [   {   'alert': {   'service_id': 'P94CEA6', 
                                  'threshold': 5,                       
                                  'type': 'pagerduty'},
                     'elastic_config': 'config',
                     'metrics': ['indid_unique_cnt', 'zs'],
                     'model_type': 'Deep_Dive',
                     'read_object': 'dqs_rtfs_d_*',
                     'source': 'elastic',
                     'target': 'elastic',
                     'target_write_index': 'dqs_target_write_index',
                     'watcher': 'cie_watch_zs_3d.json'}
    ]
}
```